# jquery background height change

Tags: jquery, html

I anm new to jquery so  I am learning the JQuery from w3schools.com .The below code is from w3sch

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $("button").click(function () {
                    $("#div1").height("200px");
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="div1" style="background:yellow;height:100px;width:100px">HELLO</div>
        <div style="background:yellow;height:100px;width:100px">W3SCHOOLS</div>
        <button>Click me</button>
    </body>
```

I saved it as some_name.htm. When I open the it in browser it is as follows:

[image]

but when i click on **Click me** there is no change in the size.

according to code and flow the height should increase

anyone knows how to get this working ??

Comment: have you put the jquery.js in the same folder??

Comment: http://jsbin.com/asiwos its working. may be u missed the jquery referance. can you check the console for errors.

Comment: Download jquery and specify the correct path [http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you do not have jquery.js in your workspace. You need to download it and give the correct path while including it -

In case you do not wish to download, use this instead -

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

I tried running your code it is working.

Comment: What is the reason for downvoting this?

Answer (score 3):

The issue is the lack of jquery being included, as pointed out by cyclotrojan, I would also suggest you get in the habit of having a local fall back as well as including the remote version as shown here, http://jsbin.com/adofej/2 my rep is to low to leave comments if you feel this doesn't qualify as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jQuery [css()](http://api.jquery.com/css/) method

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $("#div1").css('height':'200px');
});
```

and for multiple css declarations:

```
$("button").click(function(){
  $("#div1").css('height':'200px','width':'100px','background-color':'#f00');
});
```

Comment: This is not an answer for this question. Before answering check the codes. -1